# Summarize try / catch

Tags: c#, try-catch

Is there a way to get this shorter?

I have single lines with method calls but in exception case each needs a seperate error message.

```
try
{ 
    ReadFile(); 
}
catch
{ 
    Message.Show("Error reading File"); 
}
try 
{ 
    ReadData(); 
}
catch 
{ 
    Message.Show("Error reading Data"); 
}
try 
{ 
    ValidateData(); 
}
catch
{
    Message.Show("Error validating Data"); 
}
try
{
    SaveData();
}
catch 
{ 
    Message.Show("Error saving Data");
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this could be shortened. But it seems to be very clear.

Comment: You can throw different exceptions and do `try { do everything } catch(ReadException){} catch{ReadFileException} etc..`

Comment: Couldn't you just try catch them in the code of the method instead of here?

Comment: How can you ReadData if you've not read the file? How can you validate data you've not read?

Comment: @TZHX - I read multiple files and continue with the others in case one fails

Comment: Having "catch-all" (i.e. `catch` without a filter on what to catch) may not be the best approach. For starters, you might want to try `catch (Exception exception) { [log the exception somehow]; Message.Show(...); }`, which is (slightly) better, becaus now you know what *exact* exception was thrown.  And then you can refine the displayed message. For example `try { ReadFile(); } catch(FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) { Message.Show("File was not found!"); } catch(Exception exception) { [still log the exception]; Message.Show("Error reading File");}`

Comment: Just be sure to catch the more specific exceptions earlier and the more general exceptions later; with the most general `Exception` as the last one.

Answer (score 3):

Throw exceptions like this:

```
throw new Exception("Error reading File");
throw new Exception("Error reading Data");
```

and with that you can change your code

```
try
{ 
    ReadFile(); 
    ReadData(); 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ 
    Message.Show(ex.Message); 
}
```

Or you can throw specific exceptions like `ReadDataException` or `ReadFileException` and whit that

```
try
{ 
    ReadFile(); 
    ReadData(); 
}
catch (ReadFileException)
{ 
    Message.Show("Error reading File"); 
}
catch (ReadDataException)
{ 
    Message.Show("Error reading Data"); 
}
```

Comment: i don't throw there specific exceptions -they happen e.g. when the file doesn't exist

Comment: Then catch those exceptions like I show you in the second example. Other than that, you can do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place `throw new Exception(<yourMessage>)` into your methods and place this methods into one big `try..catch` block. Logically it is correcter, because every exception belongs to method, not to this realization of methods;
2. Place `try..catch` into methods and return `int` or `enum` status code from each method, and create message based on this status code;
3. Throw different types of exception, and depends on it show corresponding message;
4. Add global exception handling to your application